# Problems connecting python mapi and Outlook

Tags: python, outlook, email, email-client

I'm trying to set up an automatic job in Python 2.7.3, which shall send emails through Outlook (this can not be changed, as this is at work). I'm setting this up with win32com/mapi. When trying to send an email, I get the following message in a pop-up box: "Either there is no default mail client or the current mail client cannot fullfill the messaging request. Please run Microsoft Outlook and set it as the default mail client." By accepting this, i also get an error-message in the shell:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27_64\Lib\site-packages\win32comext\mapi\demos\mapisend.py", line 85,     in <module>
    SendEMAPIMail(SendSubject, SendMessage, SendTo, MAPIProfile=MAPIProfile)
  File "C:\Python27_64\Lib\site-packages\win32comext\mapi\demos\mapisend.py", line 23,     in SendEMAPIMail
    mapi.MAPIInitialize(None)
com_error: (-2147467259, 'Unspecified error', None, None)
```

As the text suggests, I've checked that Outlook is indeed the default mail client. This does not solve the problem. The other thing that is weird is that this exact same job is set up on an older computer we have, which this new one shall replace. On the older one it is working smooth.

Some details:
Have administrator rights on both computers.
Older pc:
Windows Vista
32 bit system
Python 2.7.3 for 32 bit system

New pc: Windows 7
64 bit system
Python 2.7.3 for 64 bit system

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

The solution became to remove the Python 64 bit version and to replace it with the 32 bit version, without deeper insight on my part as to what went wrong with the 64 bit version; my pywin32 version was 64 bit.